# What if I want to build GNU m4 from zero without bootstrap from another release copy of GNU m4?

Tags: linux, gnu, autoconf, m4

Recently I'm writing a paper associated with open sources and GNU. I need to do some testings to simulate how the pioneers of GNU develop the GNU build system from zero in the early period. But I found one strange thing in [README](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=m4.git;a=blob_plain;f=README;hb=HEAD) with the statement:

> If GNU 'm4' is meant to serve GNU 'autoconf', beware that 'm4' should be fully installed *prior to* configuring 'autoconf' itself.
> Likewise, if you intend on hacking GNU 'm4' from git, the bootstrap process requires that you first install a released copy of GNU 'm4'.

If we follow up this logic, what about the first released copy of GNU m4? Can anybody have clue or hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> If we follow up this logic, what about the first released copy of GNU m4?

[Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) would be a better forum for questions about computing history. From a technical perspective, however, it is obvious that the first version of GNU `m4` could not have depended on an Autoconf build system if Autoconf also depended on GNU `m4`, not even if they were part of the same package. In fact, GNU's `m4` is not the first or only `m4`, and it did not always have an Autoconf-based build system.  For its part, Autoconf did not always depend specifically on GNU `m4`.

Bear in mind, too, that

- `configure` scripts similar to those produced by Autoconf were originally written by hand or generated by other tools, and other, less automated approaches predated that.
- an Autoconf `configure` script itself does not ordinarily depend on Autoconf or `m4`.  This is by design.  As long as you have a complete distribution of an Autotools-based project (which, by definition, includes a `configure` script) you do not need to be able to run Autoconf or `m4` to build the project.

The Autoconf manual has [a chapter on the tool's history](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/History.html) that might interest you.

Comment: I am on a system without m4. It was cited as needed by a `configure` script. I pulled m4 from git and ran `bootstrap` where I was also told that I need m4 to build m4. Checkmate atheists. Seriously, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: @HackSlash, if you have one of the very rare `configure` scripts that require `m4` at execution time then you should first look to obtain it via your system's package management system instead of building it from source.

Comment: If you do need to build any GNU project from source then you should download its distribution tarball, such as https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.18.tar.gz, and you should follow the standard steps to build it: unpack; change to its directory; `./configure; make; sudo make install`.  *Bona fide* distributions should not require any build-system components to be rebuilt, and therefore do not, generally, require `m4` just for building.  The git repository is primarily for developers, not for people just trying to install the software.